# Universal DNS Resolver

Tags: dns, ip, python, dns-domain, domain

I would like to implement a DNS client which should be able to resolve any valid domain public, private or otherwise (tor,i2p). What's the best way to achieve this?

I know that I need to pick a particular DNS server based on the TLD, for e.g, in order to resolve Tor I should have access to Tor network.

```
if it's .onion --> local (contact tor node)   
if it's .com --> 8.8.8.8 (any public)   
if it's .tk --> 80.80.80.80 (freenom) and so on ....
```

I'm looking for an idea on different possible and efficient ways to achieve this. The few options that I know of:

1. bash script using dig, pointing to a specific dns server based on
   TLD
2. BIND dns server config based on TLD
3. writing a custom python program

Love to get your ideas. Please let me know if similar programs exist.

Comment: This does not look like a security question but a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many DNS Server implements already this logic. You can define multiple DNS server forwarder endpoints based on the domains changing the DNS server configuration file. Then you can use a standard DNS client to point to a DNS server with this configuration.

For instance [here](https://dev.to/artemis/conditional-dns-for-multiple-intranet-upstreams-with-dnsmasq-34fe) is described how to configure dnsmasq in order to forward DNS requeste to two external DNS servers based on the domain name.

Comment: Thank You, dnsmasq is the way to go !!!!, now i just need to find a way to resolve TOR and other private domains.